# List property inside a model is coming null while posting the model to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am creating a basic mvc3 application in which I am trying to post a complex model type with a list property (of model type) to my controller. But when I do so, that property is coming as null inside the model.

I have my model as follows:

```
public class EmployeeList
{
    public List<Employee> employeeList { get; set; }
}
```

And Employee is again a model :

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Code is:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    EmployeeList em = new EmployeeList();
    em.employeeList = new List<Employee>() { new Employee(){}};
    return View(em);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix = "employeeList")]EmployeeList employeeList1)
{
    .......
}
```

And the Views are as follows:

Index.cshtml:-

```
@model test.Models.EmployeeList
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "testForm" }))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.eid)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.eid)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.eid)
    <br />
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.employeeList)
    <br />
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Post" />
    </p>
}
```

And the editor template view is:

```
@model test.Models.Employee

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
<br />
<br />
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name)
```

On the browser I checked , the names and id's are generated as follows:

```
name="employeeList[0].Id", id="employeeList_0__Id"

name="employeeList[0].Name", id="employeeList_0__Name"
```

But when I post this EmployeeList model to controller, I get the employeeList as null.

Please help me if I am missing something.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think the mvc model binding might be getting confused. Try changing the name of your model's property from employeeList to ListOfEmployees. e.g.

```
public class EmployeeList
{
    public List<Employee> ListOfEmployees { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix = "ListOfEmployees")]EmployeeList employeeList1)
{
    .......
}

@model test.Models.EmployeeList
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "testForm" }))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.eid)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.eid)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.eid)
    <br />
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ListOfEmployees)
    <br />
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Post" />
    </p>
}
```

Comment: I tried changing the name of property employeeList but got the same result...@Teppic

Comment: Am I missing something else?

Comment: Did you also update the Prefix value of the Bind attribute? i.e. public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix = "ListOfEmployees")]EmployeeList employeeList1)

Comment: Yes I changed the Prefix also,but got the same result, the list was still empty...@Teppic

Comment: Could you try removing the Bind attribute from the Index action and give it another go? i.e. public ActionResult Index(EmployeeList employeeList1)

Comment: Yes it worked...:) thanks so much for all your help...@Teppic...but could you please tell me what problem this bind attribute might be causing?

Comment: OK, good news. I have got a feeling the prefix property of the bind attribute was causing the problem (which is different from what I suggested in my answer). You could try using the Include property instead, but I am not sure if you should specify a value of "Id, Name" or "ListOfEmployees". You could try both and see how you go :)

Answer (score 1):

As you have discovered, you need to remove the `BindAttribute`. To explain:

When you use `[Bind(Prefix="employeeList")]`, you are telling the `ModelBinder` to strip "employeeList" from the beginning of the name of each property that's posted back, so instead of `employeeList[0].Id` and `employeeList[0].Name` (which is correct as your posting back `class EmployeeList`) you getting `[0].Id` and `[0].Name` (but `class EmployeeList` does not have properties `Id` and `Name`.

If you use the the attribute as you have, you would need to change your parameter to

```
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix = "employeeList")]List<Employee> employeeList1)
```

which would bind correctly